# CSS div background not appearing

Tags: css, html, background

I'm new to web development, but I have been looking ofr a solution to this problem for days now, so I decided to finally ask you.

I have an empty page with a background defined in an external sylesheet.

Apart from that, I have included in the body a div which I will use to position images via the external stylesheet, rather than just inserting an  tag in the html file.

Here is my html file:

```
<! DOCTYPE html public "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

```
<head>
    <title>Azin Productions</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style_2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/MyFontsWebfontsOrderM3219563.css">
</head>

<body>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <div class="bit_1"></div>
</body>
```

and here is my stylesheet:

```
    body {
  background: url(images/NYCNEW.jpg);
  background-size:100% 130%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  z-index: -100;

  font-family: Museo-500; calibri;
}

p {
  color:orange;
}

.bit_1 {
  color:blue;
  background-image: url(images/bits/bit_1.png)
  z-index: 500
}
```

-and yes, I am absolutely sure the links are correct :)

Thanks in advance, 
Magnus

Comment: 1) Fix your doctype declaration to `<!DOCTYPE ...>`, there is no space between the exlamation mark and the word DOCTYPE. 2) If you are using an XHTML doctype all tags needs to be closed, even the single ones. Ex: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style_2.css"/>` (see the final slash / that differs from your code).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! Looks like I have to research more before posting. Hopefully I will be able to repay you at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your css file is in a folder then you need to add ../ before the image path. 
../ represents the root folder.

change the code like this

```
body {
  background: url(../images/NYCNEW.jpg);
  background-size:100% 130%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  z-index: -100;

  font-family: Museo-500; calibri;
}

.bit_1 {
  color:blue;
  background-image: url(../images/bits/bit_1.png);
  z-index: 500
}
```

You need to add ../ before the image path. ../ represents the root folder.

Comment: @SACHIN <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/MyFontsWebfontsOrderM3219563.css"> If u can observe this line then u will come to know which is the correct path. Both css files are in the folder called style. be yourself very sure before down-voting any answers.

Comment: OP said he is aboslutly sure links are correct.. @phil give the right answer :-) for background width and height has to be fix

Comment: I dnt believe in saying, I believe in my knowledge and as far my knowledge the path is wrong (If he is writing the style in the css file which is placed in a folder). He has also said he is new to web so this might be his minor mistake

Comment: for background image we need to give width and height rite ? that dont come in your knowledge ?

Comment: He is not saying only for the div, bg image problem is there for the body also. Body doesn't need width and height. if the bg image solve then it is common sense to give the width and heigt or he might be adding the content in tat div where the width and height is not necessary. Also I dnt wanna argue for dumb responses let him take his right answer

Comment: ya its commn sense bt u didnt add width and height in your code so i didnt find comn sense in your answer.lolz

Answer (score 1):

Specify a width and height for `<div class="bit_1"></div>`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing (;) and you need to give your div width and height:

```
.bit_1 
{   
color:blue;   
background-image: url(images/bits/bit_1.png); 
z-index: 500;   width:500px;   height:50px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to know how the relative path of `url(...)` images in CSS work, and is completely dependant on where the CSS is used.

If you place the CSS within your page, the relative path of `url(...)` becomes the same as the page.  If you place the CSS within a linked .css file, the relative path of `url(...)` becomes the same as the **.css file**

As your .css file is located in the `style` directory, the following command...

```
background: url(images/NYCNEW.jpg);
```

... will be translated as...

```
style/images/NYCNEW.jpg
```

In order to get around this, use a relative path from the CSS file...

```
background: url(../images/NYCNEW.jpg);
```

The reason for this behaviour is so that you can link to the .css file from multiple pages, with each page being in different directory structure if required

---

You also need to provide either some content to the `bit_1` div, or provide a `height` and `width` to the control, otherwise it will never be seen.  (Just giving a background image to a div will not make that div appear, as it is simply the background.)

Answer (score 0):

Hi now why are u define `z-index`  this work only `position` and now

change your code as like this

```
   body {
  background: url("../images/NYCNEW.jpg");
  background-size:100% 130%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;

  font-family: Museo-500; calibri;
}

p {
  color:orange;
}

.bit_1 {
  color:blue;
  background: url("../images/bits/bit_1.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

**now check to your images path and than apply**

Answer (score 0):

You don't really say what your problem is but I guess the background image isn't showing in the `.bit_1` div? If that's the case then you'll need to set a height and width on the div in order for it to show. Div's only naturally expand with content in them.

Other than that you have various errors in your CSS:

```
body {
  background: url(images/NYCNEW.jpg);
  background-size:100% 130%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;

  z-index: -100; - This will not do anything without the 'position' property set. Besides which I would never recommend using negative z-index.

  font-family: Museo-500; calibri; - The 'calibri' will be discarded here because you already ended your declaration at the first semi-colon after 'Museo-500'
}

p {
  color:orange;
}

.bit_1 {
  color:blue;
  background-image: url(images/bits/bit_1.png) - You are missing the semi-colon to end this declaration.
  z-index: 500 - Again no need for this.
}
```

Better CSS:

```
body {
  background: url(../images/NYCNEW.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 130%;    
  font-family: Museo-500, calibri;
}
p {
  color: orange;
}
.bit_1 {
  width: 500px; /* Width of your background images */
  height: 400px; /* Height of your background images */
  color: blue;
  background: url("../images/bits/bit_1.png") no-repeat;
}
```